# rails carrierwave upload image or image url error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, image-uploading

I have installed the carrierwave gem. 
my model is

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :pic_url, :rating

  mount_uploader :pic_url , ImageUploader
end
```

and my view for is

```
<%= form_for @rating, :html => {:multipart=>true} do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
       <%= f.file_field :pic_url %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :remote_pic_url_url, 'or image url' %>
      <br/>
      <%= f.text_field :remote_pic_url_url %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit 'Upload Picture', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I get an error msg `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: remote_pic_url_url`
when I remove the optional pic url field , then It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `remote_file_url` to `attr_accessible`.